# Prohibit Inserting Rows With Default Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

Is there any way of how to prevent inserting data in specified columns in table and use only the default (constraint) values?

E.g. I have columns:

```
LogInsert (DF GETDATE())
LogUser   (DF ORIGINAL_LOGIN())
```

both defined with `DEFAULT` constraint. I do not want to allow users to insert into those columns, but use default values here instead when inserting new row.

This should raise an error.

```
INSERT  INTO T1
        ( C1
        ,C2
        ,LogInsert
        ,LogUser
        )
VALUES  ( 'A'
        ,'B'
        ,'20160101 10:53'
        ,'domain\user'
        );
```

User should be able to perform the following script without error.

```
INSERT  INTO T1
        ( C1, C2 )
VALUES  ( 'A', 'B' );
```

Comment: Or force the users to call a stored procedure to insert.

Comment: I guess this needs pretty much DBA's effort? As I would need to define this for every user for every column for every table? Cant imagine the maintenance.

Comment: @jarlh that could be one of the ways. Ty for the tip.

Comment: Create a `before insert` trigger and check the values that user tries to insert into these columns. If they are not `NULL`, raise an error.

Answer (score 2):

You could always give your users a view to work against instead of a table. You can then either choose to hide the columns completely or (as here) make them computed so that they cannot insert a value into the column, via the view:

```
create table dbo._T1 (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
    Inserted datetime2 constraint DF__T1_Inserted DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME()) not null,
    ABC varchar(10) not null,
    constraint PK__T1 PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
go
create view dbo.T1
with schemabinding
as
    select
        ID,
        COALESCE(Inserted,SYSDATETIME()) as Inserted,
        ABC
    from dbo._T1
go
insert into dbo.T1 (ABC) values ('abc')
go
insert into dbo.T1 (ABC,Inserted) values ('def',SYSDATETIME())
```

Results:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.T1' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

All of the users queries continue to just use `T1`. It just happens to be a view rather than a table.

---

In the above, the view uses `COALESCE(Inserted,SYSDATETIME())`. It doesn't really matter what's used here, and it doesn't need to match e.g. the default definition. All that's important is that *some* computation is performed on the `Inserted` column so that it becomes a read-only column in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Check Constraint on the table, for example the below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T1]
(
     [C1] VARCHAR(50)
    ,[LogInsert] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,[LogUser] VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
)

ALTER TABLE [T1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_T1_LogInsert] CHECK ([LogInsert] = GETDATE())
ALTER TABLE [T1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_T1_LogUser] CHECK ([LogUser] = ORIGINAL_LOGIN())


INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ([C1]) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ([C1]) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ([C1]) VALUES ('C')

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[T1]

--Will Fail
INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ([C1],[LogInsert]) VALUES ('D','2016-11-11 00:00')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[T1] ([C1],[LogUser]) VALUES ('D','Not Your UserName')
```

OR

You can force the user to only insert using a stored procedure and not allow that as a parameter, this can be done with a table variable too for bulk inserts.